# Guice injection fails somewhere in injection hierarchy

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am new to Guice and trying to achieve dependency injection in my below family of classes as below:

```
class DoSomethingServlet {
    @Inject
    IProvider provider;
}

interface IProvider {

}

@Singleton
class Provider implements IProvider {

    @Inject
    @Named("B")
    IManager manager; 
}

interface IManager {

}

class Manager implements IManager {

    @Inject
    @Named("B")
    IDAO dao;

    @Inject
    @Named("B")
    IConverter converter;
}

interface IDAO {

}

class DAO implements IDAO {

}

interface IConverter {

}

class Converter implements IConverter {

}

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

class DoSomethingModule extends  AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IProvider.class).to(Provider.class);
        bind(IManager.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("B"))
            .to(Manager.class);
        bind(IDAO.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("B")).to(DAO.class);
        bind(IConverter.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("B"))
            .to(Converter.class);
    }
}
```

However there is some issue due to which my request does not succeed.

If I just replace the two injects in Manager with new as below it works fine.

```
IDAO dao = new DAO();
IConverter converter = new Converter();
```

Could you please help me in spotting the problem and also let me know how you debug dependency injection issues in Guice in general?

Comment: Both dao and converter inside Manager are turning out to be null which is resulting into NullPointerException. Any idea why is @Inject not working here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind your servlet through guice. For that you need to follow below steps.

Create a **Servlet module** to add servlet binding.

```
public class YourServletModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("YOUR SERVLET URL").with(DoSomethingServlet.class);
        bind(DoSomethingServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

You can also add servlet mapping to module you have already created if you don't want to create separate module, but then you need to derive your module from ServletModule.

Create Guice **listener** as below.

```
public class YourContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener{
    @Override
    public Injector getInjector(){
        return Guice.createInjector(new DoSomethingModule(),new YourServletModule());
    }
}
```

Add listener tag in your web.xml.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>qualified class name of YourContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Add **guice filter** to web.xml to map filter to servlet url pattern.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>YOUR SERVLET URL</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```